# to write a co relation in java interview

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I was asked a question in java interview its not  related to java , its based on logic .
I was given a scenario :: Suppose you have to download a site completely to local drive , but the site content is changing with time . And to be updated we have to download it again and again with the change in its content. And suppose there is a command which is telling us the % change in the site content every time . By which we can calculate the hourly % change in the website.And we are given a optimal value of % change which is when reached we should download the content. We have to calculate the appropriate time after which we will check the site to be downloaded .For this time the our actual percentage change should closest to the desired value. like if we are making thread to sleep(x). "" x=? "" to calculate x we have to define a co relation with % change in the content . Because % change is also different every time . like from 9 am to 10 am the % change was 10 % , but from 10 am to 11 am it became 50 % . so average change will be 30 % according to this average % change the sleep time should also vary so that it would be optimum for performance .for ex. if current rate of change is less (as calculated from averaging the previous changes) then the time should increase. and if rate of change is high the time of download should be lowered . for all this we have to define a co relation between avg. % change and  sleep time . 
simply : we have to predict the sleep time for next iteration on the basis of actual percentage change calculated by command and the desired value of % change. So that after sleeping for the calculated time . next time our percentage change will be nearest to the desired value.

Comment: please show us some code.

Comment: @TooTone It's based on logic

Answer (score 1):

I think we don't require a relation of sleep time with the download average. We can have two threads. One thread could download the content and the other thread could check the percentage change at a particular time from the time the last notification was sent. The download thread can be waiting and the thread that calculates the percentage change can calculate after every hour how much is the current change. If it is 100 percent, it can notify the download thread. The thread that does the calculation can sleep for 60 minutes in between the time it is checking how much is the current percent change from the last time. Then it can calculate the current percentage change from the time the last notification was sent ( that means at the time of notifying it will also clear the counters or anything that holds the percentage change current state with respect to when the last notification was sent ).

I would have probably answered that.

Comment: +1 For a good analysis. The two threads run at the same time. The percentage checking thread checks the percentage every 60 minutes and adds it to the global percentage sum and sleeps. If the global percentage sum reaches 100%, it notifies and awakens the downloader thread (which will go to sleep after each download) to do a full download of the site.

Comment: There's more to my answer ( like the time taken to download vs the likely average time for the site content to change by 100 percent etc ) and some of those things could affect the way we would want to implement this requirement, but I have ignored those parts for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for commenting guys . Firstly i also did it with wait() notify() .But the interviewer  said i that  need appropriate time after which we will download . and the % change will be closest to the desired value .i Figured it out though , by using a little maths .I calculated it by taking the desired % change  and the actual one which is calculated by the command . than see the difference and accordingly changed the time according to that . I hope it works . still waiting for result .

Comment: @imsolo if this was not a website content change problem, it would be a % of % math problem. If the % change the first time is 50 and the next time it is 20, the net percentage change relative to the initial state would be 80. The short cut formula is c = a + b + (a*b)/100, where a is initial percentage change and b is the next percentage change and c is the net percentage change with respect to the initial state. But in your case we are not dealing with things that can be measured that way. So I don't see how that math applies. I mean content change could happen anywhere. And that matters.